# How to remove menu icons in flutter ReorderableListView

Tags: list, flutter, dart, drag-and-drop, icons

When I create a **ReordableListView** with flutter there are some Icons (in the right) that appear by default :

[image]

I would like to remove them because I want to put other Icons at this place and when I do this it renders this (which is obviously not what I want) :

[image]

Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer, I just needed to add this line in my `ReordableListView` widget:

```
buildDefaultDragHandles: false,
```

Comment: It is not working. Because drag feature doesn' t work when remove this icon.
Do you know any solution for that ?

Comment: @Alperen ARICI you need to wrap your child widget by `ReorderableDragStartListener` with `key` option

Answer (score 6):

Set `buildDefaultDragHandles` to `false` and wrap your `ListTile` using `ReorderableDragStartListener` to set your item draggable.

```
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  final List<int> _items = List<int>.generate(50, (int index) => index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ColorScheme colorScheme = Theme.of(context).colorScheme;
    final Color oddItemColor = colorScheme.primary.withOpacity(0.05);
    final Color evenItemColor = colorScheme.primary.withOpacity(0.15);

    return ReorderableListView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
      // Set this false
      buildDefaultDragHandles: false,
      children: <Widget>[
        for (int index = 0; index < _items.length; index++)
          // Wrap using ReorderableDragStartListener
          ReorderableDragStartListener(
            key: Key('$index'),
            index: index,
            child: ListTile(
              tileColor: _items[index].isOdd ? oddItemColor : evenItemColor,
              title: Text('Item ${_items[index]}'),
            )
          ),
      ],
      onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
        setState(() {
          if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
            newIndex -= 1;
          }
          final int item = _items.removeAt(oldIndex);
          _items.insert(newIndex, item);
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I had to change ReorderableListView.Builder to ReorderableListView only and use childrens[] like in your example. Thanks for the tip ;)

Comment: @Nabil Ait Brahim no need to change from `.Builder` to `childrens`. Just need to wrap child by `ReorderableDragStartListener` with a `key`